# How to Print Multiple Statements to One TextView

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= doubleLength; i++) {
    doubleRate = (doubleBalance * (doubleRate/100))/12;
    doubleBalance = doubleBalance + doubleRate;
    doublePayment = (doubleBalance/doubleCount);

    TextView results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
    results.setText(doublePayment+"");

    doubleCount = doubleCount - 1;
    doubleBalance -= doublePayment;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is print out every single value of the "doublePayment" value to a TextView UI Object on the screen. However, when the for loop finishes, it only prints out one value, instead of several.

I'm porting this over from C++, so I'm used to simply using `cout` to print to the terminal.

Comment: I would advice for performance reasons to move the `TextView` lookup out of your loop. There is no need to get the reference at each iteration.

Comment: There is no need to initialize textview everytime. as suggested by Daniel Lerps it is better to do it in onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
results.setText(doublePayment+"");
```

You're re setting the text value instead of appending the whole String. A better approach would be using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 1; i <= doubleLength; i++) {
    doubleRate = (doubleBalance * (doubleRate/100))/12;
    doubleBalance = doubleBalance + doubleRate;
    doublePayment = (doubleBalance/doubleCount);

    sb.append(doublePayment);
    sb.append(" ");

    doubleCount = doubleCount - 1;
    doubleBalance -= doublePayment;
}
TextView results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
results.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Hey Luiggi, I'm pretty new to Java. Would you mind very quickly telling me why I would want to use the StringBuilder method that you showed me, versus the `results.append(doublePayment+"")` method shown above? What's the advantage? Thank you.

Comment: @navlag `StringBuilder` class is meant to create `String`s faster by appending new content to it instead of concatenating `String`s. Also, it will automatically convert the primitive value into a `String` for you (so the ugly and nasty addition of `""` can be omitted). Also, in my code, I just set the text of the `TextView` one time: at the end of the loop. Other people instead retrieve the element on every for loop iteration and concatenate the results in it. Which approach to use? The one that suits better for you.

Comment: Thank you Luiggi, that helped quite a bit. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Raghunandan suggests you do not need to initialize textview inside the loop. Move

```
TextView results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
```

outside the loop.

And instead of setText use append

```
results.append(doublePayment+"\n");
```

Comment: Thanks Hoan, I'll try this now and see how it goes.

Comment: results.append(doublePayment);results.append("\n"); append new line.

Comment: also there is no need to initialize textview everytime in the for loop. answer that part also

Comment: @Raghunandan did it on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 results.setText(results.getText().toString() +  ", " +doublePayment);
```

For better performance use a `StringBuilder`.

```
String res = new StringBuilder(results.getText().toString())
    .append(", ")
    .append(doublePayment)
    .toString();

results.setText(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the text first (in a StringBuilder or whatever), then do the setText outside the loop.

Alternately, you can do

```
results.setText(results.getText().toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + doublePayment);
```

if you don't want it outside the loop.